# Dynamic position change java fx

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create an app that follows my hand and shows it as a circle on the screen. I have coordinates of a hand, got it from Kinect. Now I would like to convert these hand coordinates into the point. That`s the easy part. But can You give me some examples of how to change the position of a circle every time I get new coordinates of a hand (like ~25 times per second)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a `Task<Point>` for reading out the Kinect output, use `updateValue` to update the `value` property and use a listener to update the circle position. (And of course make sure the task runs on a background thread...)